# Should I put this question on ServerFault or SuperUser?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm referring to this question: https://serverfault.com/q/624902/67975

Since it's about connecting to a domain, I put it on ServerFault.
But I'm considering putting it on SuperUser instead, because:

1. It's still about a client OS rather than a server OS, so it might be more relevant on SU
2. I have enough reputation on SU to put a bounty on it

I'm thinking if it doesn't get enough attention on SF I'll migrate it to SU.
Just wondering if people have any advice regarding this.

Comment: It does involve a domain controller. Most people who would have one on SU would likely be on SF as well.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: But I would expect many more people connect to domains than the number of people who know how to manage one, right? And in either case, would it be off-topic for SuperUser, or is it just a preference for SF?

Comment: I think it'd be better off remaining on [sf] - just as a preference than being offtopic

Comment: @Sathya: Ok thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd be better off remaining on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) - just as a preference than being offtopic. I'd think lot more of the audience at Server Fault would know about domnain controllers.